# Improve Simple Nested For Loop Efficiency in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply, purrr

I am a running a permutation to get a p-value. I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`; Here is what they look like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5","Gene6"), Type1 = runif(5), Type2 = runif(6), Type3 = runif(6), SizeQuintile = c(1,2,1,5,5,1),
       ExpressionQuintile = c(1,1,1,5,5,1))

df2 <- data.frame(X1 = c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene3"), Type1 = runif(3), Type2 = runif(3), Type3 = runif(3), SizeQuintile = c(1,2,1),
       ExpressionQuintile = c(1,1,1))
```

I have a nested for loop that goes through every combination of both quintiles (e.g SizeQuintile 1, ExpressionQuintile 1; then SizeQuintile 1, ExpressionQuintile 2,  etc...) and extract a value in one of the three `Type` columns.

For example, I would extract the three `Type` values that correspond to SizeQuintile1 and Expression Quintile1 in df1, and compare those values to the two `Type` values in df2.

I then append these values to two separate vectors, `vector1` and `vector2` before comparing their medians. Since I am running a permutation, I wish to do this 10,000 times.

```
permutation_number = 10000 

for(j in 1:permutation_number){
        vector1 <- c()
        vector2 <- c()
for(i in 1:5){
        for(z in 1:5){
                #Print number of genes to sample
                number_of_rows <- length(which(df1$SizeQuintile == i & df1$ExpressionQuintile == z))

                #Extract value from every combination of quintiles, append to vector
                vector1 <- append(vector1, df1[which(df1$SizeQuintile == i & df1$ExpressionQuintile == z), ]$Type1)
                vector2 <- append(vector2, df2[sample(which(df$SizeQuintile == i & df2$ExpressionQuintile == z), number_of_rows), ]$Type1)


        }

}
#Compare medians, then append resulting TRUE or FALSE value to a #vector. 
vector3 <- append(vector3, median(vector1) > median(vector2))


}
  #Compute p value
  vector3/permutation_number
```

The code works, but it is very slow. Is there a way to do this more efficiently in R?

Comment: if memory wasn't an issue id probably use `expand.grid` and a `left_join`.

Comment: Not an help for your issue, but you should avoid using the same letter `i` for two loop variables in nested loops ..

Comment: Also, I don't undestand  why you want to do it 10000 times, when each time is seems to be the same calculation ?

Comment: I am running a permutation.

Comment: Could you share a minimal sample of your data? I'm not quite sure where the `sali_sc_als` object comes from or what it contains.

Comment: I will clarify my question, it is poorly written. Thanks!

Comment: I clarified my question. Any help with this would be great!!